# how to convert video in multiple bitrate using asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, video-streaming, video-processing

I want to play one video in different bitrates. Like i uploaded one video in 1080P resolution i want play that video in 720P, 480P, 360P, 240P, 144P etc.
I want this solution in asp.net using C#.

Like youtube provide the facility to watch video in different resolutions.

Please help me regarding this.

I tried the following code but not working:

```
using Softpae.Media;
namespace ConsoleTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Job2Convert myJob = new Job2Convert();
        MediaServer ms = new MediaServer();
        myJob.pszSrcFile = "E:\\EhabVideoLibrary\\videos\\sinbad.mkv";
        myJob.pszDstFile = "E:\\EhabVideoLibrary\\videos\\sinbad.mp4";

        myJob.pszDstFormat = "mp4";
        myJob.pszAudioCodec = "aac";

        myJob.nAudioChannels = 2;
        myJob.nAudioBitrate = -1;
        myJob.nAudioRate = -1;

        myJob.pszVideoCodec = "h264";

        myJob.nVideoBitrate = -1;
        myJob.nVideoFrameRate = -1;
        myJob.nVideoFrameWidth = -1;
        myJob.nVideoFrameHeight = -1;   

        bool ret = ms.ConvertFile(myJob);            
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can use FFplay of the **FFmpeg** project. (ffmpeg.org) With FFmpeg it's possible to encode and transcode almost every codec in the resolution you want. In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands) is the use of a command line application using C# described.

I've never tried it, but there are also libraries provided for .NET using FFmpeg like this:

- ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com
- intuitive.sk/fflib

Success with it!

Here is an example code using ffmpeg (I tested it under Win7 VM):

```
using System;

    namespace ConsoleApplication_FFmpegDemo
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string inputVideo = @"C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv";
                string outputVideo = @"C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.mp4";

                string ffmpegArg = string.Format("-i \"{0}\" -vf scale=320:240 \"{1}\"", inputVideo, outputVideo);
                string ffmpegPath = @"C:\Portable\ffmpeg-win32-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
                FFmpegTask ffmpegTask = new FFmpegTask(ffmpegPath, ffmpegArg);
                ffmpegTask.Start();

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

And the `FFmpegTask`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication_FFmpegDemo
{
    public class FFmpegTask
    {
        public Process process = new Process();

        public FFmpegTask(string ffmpegPath, string arguments)
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegPath;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        }

        public bool Start()
        {
            return process.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... it'll be better if you'll provide any sample...